# No Permissions?

Tags: linux, terminal, permissions, file-permissions

I am trying to edit /etc/gai.conf.  I am able to get to it in my file folders, but I am not sure how to edit it through the terminal.

When I open it, I can view it, but not make changes like I want.  Nothing happens when I try.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: Which dist of linux? Ubuntu, Fedora, or what?

Comment: Most likely you will need root privileges to edit this file. Become a root with help of `su` command. Then you will need to edit the file. Not sure which programs do you have but I will guess: try do like that: `nano /etc/gai.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu:

1 Open Terminal by clicking the dash
    2 Type into it:

> sudo gedit /etc/gai.conf

3 Enter your password

Comment: hmmm. thank you, but its opening a blank document

Comment: Misspelling. Sorry.